# Excel--Add Text to CellA1 after evaluating contents of A1

Tags: excel, text, addition

I would really appreicate help this. 
I have a column with dates and times. Ex.
10/10/2012, 12:55
10/5/2012, 17:24
10/2/2012, 17:42
9/27/2012, 16:28
9/22/2012, 23:38

I want all of the dates in mm/dd/yyyy format so I can use the LEFT function and eliminate the time and the comma. 
Ex. `A1=10/10/2012, 12:55`
    `B1 = LEFT(B170, 10)` 
    `I get B1=10/10/2012`

The challenge is that I can't use concatenate or "&" to add a 0 before the date. 
It works in case of 9/22/2012. But not in case of 12/1/2012.

Could someone please help me figure out how I would add the 0 depending on where it is needed?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just set the cells to `mm/dd/yyyy` format?

Answer (score 1):

you could use rounddown(A1,0) and set the format to mm/dd/yyyy